# Getting Collector object from Context of ProcessWindowFunction in Flink

Tags: java, streaming, apache-flink

I'm mimicking TTL cache invalidation in **clear** step of ProcessWindowFunction and trying to access collector object used in process in clear method. Is it possible to get it using **Context** or **getRuntimeContext**.

```
public class TimedProcess extends ProcessWindowFunction<Map<String, List<String>>, Map<String, List<String>>, String , TimeWindow> {

    Map<String, List<String>> cachedValue;

    @Override
    public void clear(Context context) throws Exception {
        // How to get output used in process function here

        // Collector<Map<String, List<String>>> output = ?

        // Map<String, List<String> recentCacheValue;
        // output.collect(recentCacheValue)

    }

    @Override
    public void process(String visitorId, Context context, Iterable<Map<String, List<String>>> input, Collector<Map<String, List<String>>> output) throws Exception {

         // cache store logic
         // output.collect(cachedValue);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't work.

Comment: This looks really weird. Could we maybe go back a step and check what you are actually trying to achieve first? Why would it need to be in `clear`?

Comment: Went back and rechecked other options and found that for that usecase right way to achieve is using `ProcessFunction`, which gives me `onTimer` method to control action on trigger.